# Illustrator make paste maintain sub grouped layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I want to copy subgrouped items and paste them relative to the original object. Starting point:

[image]

However, illustrator pastes the new objects on top of the top-most item:

[image]

The desired functionality is, however, this (pasted objects are on top of their respective copied object):

[image]

Is this possible in illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the exact answer you are looking for is the option "Paste Remembers Layers" inside the Layers' panel flyout menu!

Comment: Are you certain? I still get the same behavior. I thought 'paste remembers layers' was for inter-document pasting. Is there any other trick to getting it to work? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Oh, you may not have layers, those may in fact be groups. (Do an ungroup to see if the 'layers' disappear (layers don't do that)). In this case you may need to make use of a script!
Oh you DID say 'subgrouped' - so indeed my answer here would not suffice!